# Creating a Scheduled task in Tkinter on Unix

Tags: python, unix, tkinter, cron

Through an application I have made with Tkinter, I'm trying to add a command to run a script every week. When the program is closed the command should be in forever place.

I've sifted through the documentation on cron, but there doesn't seem to be a way to edit the crontab without using the shell. Also I've looked through the 'at' command, but that only seems to run once.

My question is - How can one create a weekly recurring task by issuing a single command in Python on Unix?

If not with only 1 command, can I use multiple?

Answer (score 1):

In most modern Linux distros like Debian or Ubuntu, you can add an executable file (like a shell script or a symlink to one) into /etc/cron.weekly and it will be automatically run once a week for you. This is using the `anacron` command, which is fairly common these days.

Comment: Thank you so much for the direction. Do you know of a good place to find very clear documentation on the /etc/crontab folder?

Comment: Can't think of anything off hand other than just googling "anacron", or "cron" + whatever distro you're using.

Comment: Thanks. I found that if I copy the crontab to a tmp file, edit that file, I can then declare that file as my crontab, and then delete said tmp file.